# How to send a POST request with Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: rest, post, tornadofx

I am trying to send a POST request from my TornadoFX application to my nodejs server.

That's how i send my request to the server:

```
val api: Rest by inject()

api.baseURI = "http://localhost:5000/"

api.post("api/register", userModel) {
    it.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
}
```

My UserModel looks like this:

```
class UserModel : JsonModel {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
    var name by nameProperty

    val emailProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
    var email by emailProperty

    override fun toJSON(json: JsonBuilder) {
        with(json) {
            add("name", name)
            add("email", email)
        }
    }
}
```

Printing the request body on my node server i get following:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  '{"name":"Test","email":"test@test.org"}': ''
}
```

When i send a request via Postman i get the following body:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  name: 'Test',
  email: 'test@test.org'
}
```

And that's what i'm trying to produce with TornadoFX without success.
I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly setting the Content-Type header, but you're pushing a JsonModel as your data, and consequently the framework will convert it to a JSON structure by calling `toJSON()` on it. The application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type expects an URL encoded piece of data, so you need to convert your data into an url encoded string. I suggest adding a function to your domain model like this:

```
fun toURLEncoded() =
   "name=${name.urlEncoded}&email=${email.urlEncoded}".byteInputStream(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

This example uses an extension function called `urlEncoded` to avoid clutter. You can define that extension function like this for example:

```
fun Any.urlEncoded(): String = URLEncoder.encode(toString(), "UTF-8")
```

Now you just have to call `api.post("api/register", userModel.toURLEncoded())` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated TornadoFX from version 1.7.17  to version 1.7.19 and now it works without encoding the values.